# iOS: write data to json file programatically

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, writefile

My json file look like this:

```
{
  "images": [
  "straight up kick.png",
  "women kick.png",
  "Taekwondo Kanji vertical.png",
  "face kick3.png",
  "flexibility.png",
  "Punch.png",
  "hook kick.png",
  "front kick 2.png"
 ]
}
```

i am reading above json programmatically like below:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"generated" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSMutableArray * jsonimages = [dict objectForKey:@"images"];
NSLog(@"images %@", jsonimages);
```

i want to add more items to array named as jsonimages by writing to json file programmatically.
Json file name is generated.json.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Is your issue adding objects in `dict` (note it's not mutable), `jsonimages` or saving it back? Because you can't write into `[NSBundle mainBundle]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)writeStringToFile:(NSString*)aString {

    // Build the path, and create if needed.
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName = @"generated.json";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    }

    // The main act...
    [[aString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
}

- (NSString*)readStringFromFile {

    // Build the path...
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName = @"generated.json";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    // The main act...
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```